# Is it useful to write an ODE in terms of dimensionless variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have seen several ODEs where different variables in the equation are not dimensionless. However, in the process to solve the ODE the equation is first written in terms of dimensionless variables.

Some examples:

1. Lane-Emden Equation in stellar astrophysics (See Carrol and Ostille, An Introduction to Modern Astrophysics)
2. The ODE for modelling insect outbreak (See Strogatz, Non Linear Dynamics and Chaos)

What's the use of this  *nondimentionalisation* process?

One usefulness that I can obviously deduce is that the process makes the ODE look more neat. Other than this, I don't know any. I have searched the internet and this site to find the answer. But, I have only found some articles/questions describing the algorithm for nondimentionalisation.

What other use, if any, does nondimentionalisation have?